# Readonly toolbar item - valid or invalid - iPhone Human Interface Guideline?

Tags: iphone

The toolbar of our iPhone app contains an icon to indicate online/offline status. Since the icon is just an indication of online/offline status, it is readonly or say 'not-clickable'.

My question is - Does an item in toolbar has to perform some action or can it be readonly icon ?

Will it create any problem in future while submitting app to appstore ?

Thanks in advance,
--Prem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Technically nobody can forbid to insert "readonly" item there.

Apple does it, for example, in Mail.app (in the mail list, "Updated ..." and updating state in the bottom of the screen).

Everything in HIG is not a dogma. You can use something differently if it does not use private API and you understand why. If you do not know what is right — use HIG and Apple applications as a suggestion.

Only one advice. Make sure that user won't be confused with this UI element. If it will look same as an action element, that he can press, that will be a bad solution. Otherwise it's absolutely OK.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your answer sounds pretty convincing. I will keep in mind your suggestion about the appearance of readonly icon.